# Why won't the return value print from the jQuery $.post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, yourls

First, let's start with the code.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    tabURL = tab.url;
    $.post("http://s.mxtm.me/yourls-api.php",
        { signature: "XXXXXXXXXX", 
          action: "shorturl", 
          url: tabURL, 
          format: "simple" 
        },
        function(data) { 
            $("body").append(data);
        });
```

I'm working on a little Chrome extension as a client for YOURLS, and I'm using the jQuery `$.post` function to interact with the YOURLS API.

Under `function(data) {` I'm attempting to print the return from my POST. I've tried appending, I've tried alerting, I've tried document.writing, but nothing works. Does anyone have any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: You're probably getting an error. The callback for the function only runs on `success`.

Comment: This doesn't seem likely to me, as the URL shortens successfully and can be viewed from the admin panel.

Comment: @MaxTamer-Mahoney I think what Blender's saying is that it looks like your success function isn't being called (this is certainly the case if a single alert does nothing), which must mean your call isn't successful. Many things can go wrong after the shortened URL is created. At the very least check Firebug or Fiddler for a non-200 response

Comment: I actually can't check either of those as 1. I'm on a Mac and 2. I'm making a Chrome extension lol.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools has the same functionality as Firebug where you can see all HTTP requests and responses. Just click on any request in the `Network` tab.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that the ajax call is failing, add an error callback to see what's wrong:

```
$.post(
    "http://s.mxtm.me/yourls-api.php", 
    { signature: "XXXXXXXXXX", action: "shorturl", url: tabURL, format: "simple" },
    function(data) {   $("body").append(data); }
).error(function(xhr,error,ex) { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: @Strelok: you passed error arguments, but you didn't `alert()` them ;)

Comment: @Blender I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: According to Chrome, the request was "canceled", but I have no idea what that means. Ideas?

Comment: @MaxTamer-Mahoney you need to CLICK the request and inspect the `Response` tab to see what the server returned.

Comment: Now Chrome is telling me that there is no response. From what I'm seeing, it looks like an Access Denied

Comment: Maybe you didn't setup YOURLS correctly if you are getting access denied. I think you should start a new question that is relevant YOURLS so people who know can help you.